# How to make it roll multiple times

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to be able to have a person specify how many sets of dice they want to roll. at present if they want to roll three sets of a `d100` they have to enter the command 3 times. I want to be able to have them enter an amount  like `!3d100` and have it roll it 3 times?

```py
@client.command(name='d100', help='Rolls a d100 sice')
async def dice(context):
    diceEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Rolling for " + str(context.message.author.display_name), color=0xCC5500)
    roll = (random.randint(1, 100))
    url = "http://157.230.225.61/images/dice/d100/d100_{:03}.png"
    url = url.format(roll)

    diceEmbed.set_image(url=url)
    diceEmbed.add_field(name="d100", value=roll, inline=True)

    if roll == 1:
        diceEmbed.set_footer(text="FUMBLE")

    await context.message.channel.send(embed=diceEmbed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all consider using `f string`. You will have to add a input to your command `!dice 3` This will give you 3 rolls if no amount given only 1.

Keep in mind in embed you can only place one image so i took the highest according to you.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dice(ctx, amount: int = 1):

    diceEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"Rolling for {ctx.message.author.display_name}", color=0xCC5500)
    max_roll = 0

    for i in range(amount):
        roll = (random.randint(1, 100))
        if roll > max_roll:
            url = f"http://157.230.225.61/images/dice/d100/d100_{roll:03d}.png"
            max_roll = roll

        diceEmbed.add_field(
            name=f"Role number {i+1}", value=roll, inline=False)

        if roll == 1:
            diceEmbed.set_footer(text="FUMBLE")

    # You can have only one image which is the highest
    diceEmbed.set_image(url=url)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=diceEmbed)
```

Comment: So that is a great point how would I make it so it only takes the image of the highest roll?

Comment: Sure i added it above